# Positioning text inside a UL separate to the a:

Tags: html, css, class, positioning

Really simple question for CSS 101, Really simple question for CSS 101, Really simple question for CSS 101, Really simple question for CSS 101,
Really simple question for CSS 101, Really simple question for CSS 101,
Really simple question for CSS 101, Really simple question for CSS 101,

```
<div class="headercss">

    <div class="headerlogo">

    </div>

    <div class="nav">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">BLINK</a>BLINK</li>
            <li><a href="#news">BLINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">BLINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">BLINK</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>



</div>

/* BODY */

body {
    margin: 0px;
}


.headercss {
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.headerlogo {
    width: 980px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}

.nav {
    width: 980px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}

nav.ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav.ul.li {
    float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    height: 58px;
    width: 243px;
}

a:hover, a:active {
}
```

Comment: in your CSS, i see that you declare a class called ul that will target nav. Also, some of your navs are not classes at all. Take in mind that: `element.class` will make the element, just that element to have that class, neither it's children will have it

Comment: If you want to target an LI inside NAV, do > nav ul li {} instead of nav.ul.il {}

Comment: What is the container, and what is the text, in your code? I can't understand what's your goal..

Comment: It might help to specify what your end goal is, what do you want to style exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ul and li are not classes, they are tags. so should be targeted using the default tag like:

```
ul li {some style}
```

Comment: not sure why you'd want to use two separate tags for the same element, but why not use the     .nav li {background: red;}     for the background colour and to style the link text use     .nav li a {color: green;}